# Magento 2 Production Mode Issue

Tags: magento2, deploy

Can we set developer to production mode on the local server?

Magento 2.x
Php 7.x

Comment: yes you can set.

Comment: Ok, I tried but class does not exist got the issue.

Comment: Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/usr/bin/php7.0 -f /var/www/html/home/outdoorkitchen/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the mode from developer to production on the local server.

Please run the following command:

**php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production**

You can refer the Magento developer documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set production mode on local

Use below command

clear the contents of following directories:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static
```

Display the current mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

Change to production mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Change to developer mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: @Masud Shaikh please accept this answer . it's save other developer R&D time